# Переключение фона кнопкой?

Tags: html

Помогите разобраться ничего не понимаю.
Есть код- мне нужно сделать его нормальной кнопкой изменить фон, и далее что бы по нему был задан один цвет и возвращался к исходному фону по умолчанию. Исходный фон по умолчанию это видео. Помогите пожалуйста!
Вот код

````
var colorArray = [ "#f2f3f4" ]; // массив с цветами
var i = 0; // итератор

function changeColor() {
    var currentColor = colorArray[i];
    document.body.style.background = currentColor;
    localStorage.setItem('backgroundColor', currentColor);
    i++;
    if( i > colorArray.length - 1){
        i = 0;
    }
}

</script>
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:changeColor();"/> 

<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    document.body.style.background = localStorage.getItem('backgroundColor');
  };
</script>```
````

Comment: Я тут первый раз и поэтому ищу как удалить вопрос xD

Comment: Вы же писали что, ваш код рабочий для фас. Так в чем помощь нужна?