# Переключение фона по клику?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

Дело в том что я создаю сайт на Wordpres, и код мне для подвала в виджеты `HTML`

У меня переливающий фон, и суть в том пользователь может одной кнопкой изменить фон например на белый, далее вернуть по умолчанию.

Вот код который работает у меня:

```
<script>
var colorArray = [ "#f2f3f4" ]; // массив с цветами
var i = 0; // итератор

function changeColor() {
    var currentColor = colorArray[i];
    document.body.style.background = currentColor;
    localStorage.setItem('backgroundColor', currentColor);
    i++;
    if( i > colorArray.length - 1){
        i = 0;
    }
}

</script>
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:changeColor();"/> 

<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    document.body.style.background = localStorage.getItem('backgroundColor');
  };
</script>
```

Comment: Удалите пожалуйста предыдущий вопрос! И на будущее, не обязательно задавать новый вопрос, можно нажать кнопку "править" под вопросом и изменить его.

Comment: Извините, я понял

Comment: а где вопрос собственно?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Переключение фона кнопкой?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1228110/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9)